# Факториал, некорректное отображение числа. Си

Tags: c, типы, int, факториал

Есть функция `factorial`, вычисляющая факториал переданного числа.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long int factorial(unsigned short number) {
    if (number > 1) return number * factorial(number - 1);
    else return 1;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("!4  = %13d\n", factorial(4)); // 24
    printf("!10 = %13d\n", factorial(10)); // 3628800
    printf("!12 = %13d\n", factorial(12)); // 479001600
    printf("!13 = %13d\n", factorial(13)); // 1932053504 (6227020800)
    printf("!15 = %13d\n", factorial(15)); // 2004310016 (1307674368000)
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Переменная типа `unsigned long long int` может хранить в себе целое число в диапазоне от `0` до `18446744073709551615`. В этот диапазон входит факториал числа `20`. (Факториал числа `21` уже больше). Но моя программа начинает выводить неверный результат начиная с факториала числа `13`. (В комментарии написал, что выводит программа, а в скобках указал, что я ожидал увидеть).

Что не так?

Comment: попробуйте `%13llu`

Comment: @int3, понял, работает, спасибо.